# Run app on real device with a lower API (Android OS Version)

Tags: android

I have an HTC Wildfire with Android 4 on it. I'm developing an Android app with eclipse  (android 2.1, ADT 16, API 7) because I want everybody to download the app from android 2.1 to 4.

On Run configuration (manual tab) in eclipse, I cannot see a device compatible with the target(2.1)

The usb debug is activated. I have the driver for the phone. What might the problem be?

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to install sdk version 7 as well through sdk manager,  but this will only be used to create an avd for the emulator, if you are testing/debugging on the device, you can only debug as api level 15 (ICS).

Comment: thx for your response , I'm running on the emulator already... the problem is with apli 15 there chance that the app will not be supported by lower Android . How get that app run on my HTC?

Comment: You only need to set the min_sdk and target_sdk in your manifest. In this case target would be api level 15 and min_sdk would be 7. The target you select should be installed on your computer, the min_sdk doesn't have to be. If your phone doesn't appear then the drivers aren't installed properly, run ddms and see if your device is listed.